# Any way to take PDF output from SSRS 2005 and convert to a Word Doc?

Tags: reporting-services

We are using SSRS 2005 and I am looking for a way to convert a PDF output to a Word document.

We have an Asp.Net MVC 2 website, which calls the SSRS 2005 web service and does a Reponse.BinaryWrite of the web services output bytes to render the PDF of the report to the user.

I'm hoping to find a component that can take the output bytes and convert them to a Word doc, if it's free, all the better!

I'm aware SSRS 2008 has an export to Word document but upgrading is not an option just now, due to the classic excuses of time restraints and money :-(

Removing SSRS 2005 for another reporting solution is also not an option for the same reason.

I realise the parameters are incredibly tight, so any options greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

theres a couple of free online options ([http://www.pdftoword.com)](http://www.pdftoword.com/) but if you might stuggle if the pdf's its exporting have been vectorised. You might be able to use Ghostscript to convert them as well.

Comment: Yeah, aware of that site, and desktop tools. I am looking for a component I could reference in the site. thanks anyway.